# Recognize form text input email address and send an email without server processing

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am currently studying web development at college and part of my course is to create a website for a mobile company that sells phones and they sell them online.

I'm trying to create a login and signup form but currently struggling to get my form to identify and use the email that the user inputs to send an email to them verifying that they have submitted is it possible and if so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need **some** sort of server-side processing in order to send email. You'll need to make use of the form's `action` attribute to post the submitted data to a server-side script that processes the information, crafts an email, then sends it out.

Comment: what server side language are you using for this project?

Comment: More details, what database, what backend, nodejs? php? nginx server or apache? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest is in your server backend, whether it be PHP, NodeJS, etc
that you register the user in your database and have a boolean value named

> 'validated' true|**false**

set default to false, also generate a unique hash and assign it to that user under something like

> 'validate_hash':gnOOBhgenl2g432noug24g42

Use whatever function your backend server provides (or a library) to generate a unique has, and save this to the newly registered user

Then use a mail function to email the user with a link that will 'verify' them, by adding the unique has to a post url like this:

> example.com/register/verify?hash=gnOOBhgenl2g432noug24g42&email=example@mail.com

Obviously you will have to create a script at that location and handles the link and checks the hash value given against the mail provided in the database
If the hash value matches, you can update the users status to

> 'verified'**true**

And they can now access services normally.

Majority of this wont need fancy outside libs or complicated coding, just follow what I suggested and google the things I mentioned if you need to figure out a particular element, or comment/msg me!